# DigitalOcean Loadbalancer: Slow TCP connections when traffic is higher

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, digital-ocean, haproxy, nginx-ingress

**Edit** This question used to be focused on the Kubernetes side of things. It is now apparent that the problem is at the Digitalocean Loadbalancer level.

I'm in the process of moving our service from Docker Swarm to a Kubernetes setup. The new K8S environment is up and running and I am starting to switch over traffic to the new K8S setup. However, when the traffic seems to be ramping up, it slows to a halt. The browser just spins for a while and then it loads snappily.

Running a simple `curl -vvv https://thehostname.com` and this happens

```
*   Trying 12.123.123.123...
* Connected to thehostname.com (12.123.123.123) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 594 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
```

Then it pauses on that line for a while and after around 30 seconds it loads the rest of the request.

The symptom is that when the amount of traffic increases, the response time increases. It starts at 0.5 seconds, and then steadily increases to 30 seconds and is caped there. When I turn off traffic, the response time goes back to normal. The number of requests per second isn't more than 20-30 at most when this starts happening.

It seems that the act of opening a TCP connection is the slow part. I'm in contact with DigitalOcean support, but so far it has not yielded anything as it probably needs to be escalated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: No, we ditched their kubernetes offering for this reason. I think I spent a month trying to debug this which is way too much when the tech team consists of 1 person...

Comment: uh.. ok... sound bad for DO..

Comment: @BvuRVKyUVlViVIc7 they have released larger versions of their loadbalancers that accomodate more open TCP connections. A weird workaround I know... But it's sad that this is still happening. I ran into this 2 years ago. Have you contacted their support? Maybe they know more

Answer (score 1):

Issue most likely is with the number of certificates in /etc/ssl/certs.
It says that 594, certs are found. Do you really need all of them. Validate them and remove unwanted ones. Also try to copy all certs into file instead of maintaining one file for each cert

Comment: This is something that happens in different browsers on different machines, Pingdom sees the 30 second requests and times out, my local machine, etc. This example just happened to run on a webserver with a lot of certificates. So I doubt it has anything to do with it? Or am I missing something?